# Creating a "video" from gif and mp3 using javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, video, gif, animated-gif

I'm looking to embed videos in a website I am designing. After some research it looks like its going to be best to host video with a third party provider (YouTube, Vimeo, etc) due to the variety of video formats and browser incompatibilities. I intend to have lots of videos but they will only be 20 seconds long each. The audio will need to stay in sync with the video (eg in the case of speech).

Before I fully commit to using a third party provider I was thinking another solution might be to use some clever javascript to queue up a gif and an audio file (eg mp3) in sync and then play them when the user hits *Go*. Gifs are cross-browser compatible, unlike video streams. I imagine both the gif and the audio would have to be fully loaded before allowing it to be played, otherwise the "video" would get out of sync with the sound.

I just thought I'd check and see if there are any javascript libraries out there that already do something like this. And also if its even a feasible idea? Are there any fatal flaws that would render such an idea impossible or impractical?

Comment: Feasible? Yes. Impossible? See first answer. Impractical? Yes. If you use a third party service for videos, you don't have to worry about compatibility. If you ran video without a third party, using MP4 and WebM will cover any compatibility problems except with case edges which I really can't recall any at this time.

Comment: Mp4 is not supported by Chromium and Opera

Comment: That explains why I can't recall, Chromium is not mainstream, it is for developer's to build their own version of Chrome. As you can see [here](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-ww-monthly-201504-201604) Opera is well under the edge. But they do support WebM, which I have already suggested that you use. Although those two **edge** cases are not the reason why I suggested WebM. The reason why is because there is a good amount of older Macs that cannot play MP4 when using Firefox.